# magnific popup ajax with bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i'm using magnific popup ajax call and bootstrap 3, the close button is not on top right of the modal:
[my modal](https://f.cloud.github.com/assets/4982176/1843934/05ae4b66-74eb-11e3-86e0-184cb091dcb6.png)

How to make that like this :
[my dream modal](https://f.cloud.github.com/assets/4982176/1843933/e8f4f362-74ea-11e3-9483-b0a04abc100d.png)

This is my code :

```
popup = $.magnificPopup.instance;
$('a.change_photo,a.change_password,a.jabatan,a.departemen').click(function(){
    popup.open({
        items: {src:$(this).attr('url')},
        type: 'ajax',
        closeOnContentClick:false,
        closeOnBgClick:false,
        enableEscapeKey:true
      }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a CSS issue. You can just move the button over. I believe they are just absolutely positioning that button.